# Vertical to Horizontal inline alignment

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have the following 3 wrappers each one with the icon inside. I need to put the 3 logos inline, horizontally side by side above the lettering.

How can I do that?

[image: example]

https://jsfiddle.net/Pumizo/37m8v1x8/

```
<a href="index.html" id="logo">

    <span class="pennant"><span class="icon fa-camera"></span></span>
    <span class="pennant"><span class="icon fa-truck"></span></span>
    <span class="pennant"><span class="icon fa-heart"></span></span>
    <h1>EURO-TRUCKS.org</h1>
    </a>

/* Logo */

            #logo .pennant {
                font-size: 1.25em;
                margin-right: 0.75em;
            }

            #logo h1 {
                letter-spacing: 0.1em;
                font-size: 1.75em;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            .homepage #logo {
                text-align: center;
            }

                .homepage #logo .pennant {
                    display: block;
                    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
                    font-size: 2.5em;
                }

                .homepage #logo h1 {
                    display: block;
                    font-size: 2.5em;
                }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` to do that

```
#logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Stack snippet

```css
/* Logo */
#logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
#logo .pennant {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
#logo h1 {
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  text-align: center;
}
.homepage #logo * {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<a href="index.html" id="logo">
  <span class="pennant"><span class="icon fa-camera">1</span></span>
  <span class="pennant"><span class="icon fa-truck">2</span></span>
  <span class="pennant"><span class="icon fa-heart">3</span></span>
  <h1>MY QUOTE</h1>
</a>
```

---

Added sample based on comment, horizontal layout, centered

```css
/* Logo */
#logo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center
}
#logo .pennant {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
#logo h1 {
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  text-align: center;
}
.homepage #logo * {
  font-size: 2.5em;
}
```

```html
<a href="index.html" id="logo">
  <span class="pennant"><span class="icon fa-camera">1</span></span>
  <span class="pennant"><span class="icon fa-truck">2</span></span>
  <span class="pennant"><span class="icon fa-heart">3</span></span>
  <h1>MY QUOTE</h1>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked as I needed. Now I only need to center all this relative to the blue frame. I updated the question with one more image. How can I do it?

Comment: @Pumizo Added a 2:nd sample